# Sum over a mask: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, typeerror, mask

I'd like to generate a circular mask and then estimate the sum within the said mask:

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.zeros((1500,1500), dtype=bool)

y,x = np.ogrid[-750:750, -750:750]

mask[ x**2+y**2 <= 750**2 ] = True

tot = np.nansum(image[mask])
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Image is part of a much longer code that is too long to put here; plus, that is not what generates the error, that is produced by the indexing of mask. However, despite knowing where the mistake is, I am not able to fix it in any way.

What am I missing?

Comment: The code works fine to me using a random numpy array. Are you sure that `image` is in your case a numpy array and not just a list? Can you add the part where you declare `image`?

Comment: Actually, ```image``` is indeed an image that undergoes some processing before reaching this point, so I am not sure if I could add it here. Can you show me how you built the numpy array you used? At least I know that the issue is there.

Comment: Basically, `image = np.random.randint(0, 256, (1500, 1500, 3))`. If you print `type(image)` it returns `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Make sure that the image you give to `np.nansum()` is indeed a numpy array.  Anyway, it is always good practice to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to get help. So you know for the future :)